# Problem installing Broadcom BCM43142 on HP Pavilion 15-p073TX NB PC

Tags: 14.04, wireless, apt, kernel, broadcom

I know this sounds similar but my problem is unique. I have a new HP Pavilion 15-p073TX NB PC. Recently I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 but was not able to start WIFI. I searched a bit and got some answers [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers). But nothing seems to be working till now.

`lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` gave me the following:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
Region 0: Memory at b5500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` gives me the following error:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dkms fakeroot libfakeroot
Suggested packages:
  dpkg-dev debhelper
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source dkms fakeroot libfakeroot
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,271 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,564 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 163826 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libfakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Preparing to unpack .../fakeroot_1.20-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.16.0-30-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.16.0-30-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-30-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.141+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libfakeroot:amd64 (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.20-3ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download from http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download and install, the version you have doesn't have the needed patches to work with the 3.16 kernel

Comment: you have given the link to utopic..will it work on trusty??

Comment: It will and I am surprised it isn't in the trusty repos yet

Comment: Thank you. I've been going ******* crazy after upgrading to 3.16 kernel and was on the brink of rolling back (not much fun with no internet!). Installing the utopic bcmwl-kernel-source package instantly fixed my wifi.

Answer (score 0):

We had the problem of wifi not working in Acer Aspire e5 new laptop after installing ubuntu 14. We also tried to install the driver using the following command.

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

But we got the error that the package could not be found. Later found solution by giving the command

sudo apt-get update

This had then updated all the packages. After this, the installation of bcmwl-kernal-source started to work.

After installation, the wifi started to work !! Thanks for the above post.

Regards,
Gopinath