# Wireless Internet Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, internet, network-bridge, additional-drivers

I have a PC with a wireless network adapter called: `ASUS PCE-AC68`

After entering the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` I can see it is found and called:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11account wireless network adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03). Kernel drive: bcma-pci-bridge
```

My problem is that I don't get the option to find wireless networks available, only Ethernet is an option for network.

Comment: use this method by luis alvadro this can help you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: So I did all he wrote, but I'm obviously unable to update and the bcwml-kernel-source is still not located as before. This is so frustrating...

Comment: Can I download the bcwml-kernel-source on my phone and then transfer it to the pc?

Comment: try this ,  method by chili555 . midas has same problem as of your network adaptor http://askubuntu.com/a/592666/427621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I believe I solved it with installing the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and then reboot.

Comment: It says: "unable to locate package bcwml-kernel-source. Where can I get that?

Comment: Nope. Still says unable to locate :-(

Comment: Do you have a ethernet connection to locate the packages?

Comment: You could try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/588091/problem-installing-broadcom-bcm43142-on-hp-pavilion-15-p073tx-nb-pc

Comment: The link that was given in the answer gives error 404 :-(

Comment: I'll try to use ethernet connection and the rerun the lines I've been given about the bcwml-kernel-source.